# Error when trying to deploy standard OpenZeppelin ERC777 contract to ganache-cli using the brownie framework

Tags: ethereum, ganache, openzeppelin, brownie

I am familiarizing myself with smart contract development using the brownie framework and solidity. To start of I was using the `brownie console` to deploy some standard OpenZeppelin token contracts.

I did this by copying the code right from their documentation and adjusting the imports to work with brownie, like in this page: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/erc777

It works fine for the ERC20 and the ERC721 contracts. The ERC777 however always get reverted and gives me a transaction without error message, where none of the tracing methods work, because they are not implemented for a deployment transaction.

**Code For ERC777 Token (Not Working)**

```
// contracts/GLDToken.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.0.0/contracts/token/ERC777/ERC777.sol";

contract GLDToken is ERC777 {
    constructor(uint256 initialSupply, address[] memory defaultOperators)
        public
        ERC777("Gold", "GLD", defaultOperators)
    {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply, "", "");
    }
}
```

**Code For ERC20 Token (Working)**

```
// contracts/TestToken.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.0.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract TestToken is ERC20 {
    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) public ERC20("Gold", "GLD") {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
    }
}
```

**Output In Brownie Console**

```
>>> t1 = TestToken.deploy(1e21, {'from': accounts[0]})
Transaction sent: 0x33de3fadb7ccf2dd8b3841365ad88190c3486a803f6ea30c04ef8c0111ec9cbd
  Gas price: 0.0 gwei   Gas limit: 6721975   Nonce: 2
  TestToken.constructor confirmed   Block: 4   Gas used: 721166 (10.73%)
  TestToken deployed at: 0x8c81630387e9507739fCeB6cbB14Ea1Da11D2339

>>> t2 = GLDToken.deploy(1e21, [], {'from': accounts[1]})
Transaction sent: 0xca91d510e7a54099182fe218ff0ec55c62ccb06227afbe9d9497790e35776651
  Gas price: 0.0 gwei   Gas limit: 6721975   Nonce: 0
  GLDToken.constructor confirmed (reverted)   Block: 5   Gas used: 260948 (3.88%)
```

I have also tried to enter a valid address (of deployed operator contract) in the list for a default token operator, that is passed as the second parameter to the deploy function of the GLDToken. Unfortunately it made no difference.

I have exhausted all possibilities with the deploy function and am getting no further debugging information. Has anyone experienced a similar problem, or knows how to debug this further? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: having the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I am as well... any luck?

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue with the ERC777 contract from openzeppelin. I could not find a sufficient answer online so I wanted to share what worked for me. I rendered a flat file of the contract. On my line 772:
`IERC1820Registry internal constant _ERC1820_REGISTRY = IERC1820Registry(0x1820a4B7618BdE71Dce8cdc73aAB6C95905faD24);`

I deployed an ERC1820 registry locally and replaced that address.

[Registry](https://etherscan.io/address/0x1820a4B7618BdE71Dce8cdc73aAB6C95905faD24#code)

I was then able to deploy the ERC777.

Hope that works and helps.

Comment: Unclear what the link is for. If it's image use stackoverflow's imgur. If it's code, use markdown.

Comment: The link points to the registry contract on etherscan.io that can be deploy locally.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to deploy it on local blockchain, you should at first deploy the ERC1820 contract and then deploy the ERC777, BUT on other blockchains ( including testnets and mainnets this 1820 contract is already deployed and you can just use that, its is my repository on github than I deployed a ERC777 contract with a function to check if 1820 not deployed (like on the local blockchain) I deploy it first, otherwise I continue with the deploying ERC777 , I used hardhat to deploy that, but its easy to change it with other lib that you like.

https://github.com/EhsanParsania/ERC777

-- read the readme.md first